# Display calendar inside Android app

Tags: android, calendar

I'm currently developing an Android app, which loads events from a server using JSON and stores the event data into a local SQLite database.

I want to display the calendar events from within the app. If the device is in portrait mode, the calendar should be displayed in month view and if the device is in landscape mode it should be displayed in week view. Of course the events should be clickable.

Could anyone point me in the right direction by showing me an example of something similar? The whole thing should be possible for Android 1.6 onwards.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any builtin calendar in Android SDK. But there are some opensource solutions. I have just started using this calendar from http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/

It will need some customization but looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

The CalendarView does not have a setAdapter(). You could either use a gridView with # of columns set to 7 or a scrollView and construct your own grid.